# "The story was so ____ that I cannot tell what will happen." - what will be the required word here?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, exam-questions

"The story was so ____ that I cannot tell what will happen."

a) terrible b) good c) short d) funny

The book said the answer is (a). However, I can't understand the reasoning behind their choice.

In my opinion, both (a) and (c) can be chosen as an answer. Heck, (b) and (d) work as well. Why did the book go with (a) then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is 'The story *is* so  ____ that I cannot tell what will happen.' (NOT was)

'Terrible' is the correct answer. (The story is so terrible. I cannot tell...)

'The story is so *short* that I cannot tell what will happen.' does not make sense. If the story was short, we could tell it to somebody. We can tell a short story. But it is difficult to tell a story which is terrible.

We use 'so + adjective + that' to show the result. It is used to indicate that something happens extremely.

(He is so weak that he cannot walk. I am so tired that I cannot speak.)